Is it time to phase out the identification tag?
Let's self-evaluate, guys. We have model-identification, piece-identification, and may soon have bag-identification. I know we've asked about merging stuff into basic identification, but I personally propose that we remove this tag, because there is no generic ID question that doesn't fall under the aforementioned three that I know of. Ideas? Anything blindingly obvious I'm missing?

This is a good call. There are currently 163 questions tagged as identification questions. 
I will be going through the list to ensure any identification tagged questions are either tagged as piece-identification or set-identification as is the case per question. 
I'm sure there will be a few identification questions that neither fall under 'pieces' or 'sets' but they appear to be very few and they can be addressed individually. 
This may take some time, but I encourage everyone who is capable of doing so to re-tag, edit or suggest edits for these questions.
P.S. I think we also need to clearly distinguish the difference between piece-information and part-identification
UPDATE: The identification has been replaced. 
New tags include minifigure-identificaiton and set-identification.

I have contacted a moderator to make sure the new identification tags include the 'how-to-ask' tooltips.
